# Render VAAPI surface with using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, ffmpeg, vaapi

My project is to use the VAAPI hardware acceleration linked with FFmpeg.

I managed to decode with VAAPI however I would like to be able to display the video coming out of VAAPI using OpenGL.

Are there functions that allow this?

I know that for that you have to play with VAAPI's surface `VASurfaceID` but I do not see how...

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions `vaCreateSurfaceGLX()`, `vaCopySurfaceGLX()` and `vaCopySurfaceGLX()` for that purpose. There is other alternatives using DRM and EGL, but in my opinion are much more difficult to achieve. You can find an example using EGL in [mpv source code](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/video/out/hwdec/hwdec_vaapi_gl.c).